# Constructing a rocket form with fields unknown at compile-time

Tags: post, rust, rust-tokio, rust-rocket

With the Rocket web framework I can parse, error check, and use the data of a form with fields known ahead of time, like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, FromForm)]
struct Submission<'v> {
    foo: &'v str,
    bar: i32,
    baz: f32,
    qux: bool,
}

#[post("/", data = "<form>")]
fn post<'r>(form: Form<Contextual<'r, Submission<'r>>>) -> Template {
    if let Some(ref submission) = form.value {
        println!("valid: {:?}", submission);
    }

    Template::render("base", &form.context)
}
```

How would I do the same thing, if the names, types, and number of fields **isn't fixed at compile time** (instead being populated from a JSON).

Running `cargo expand` to view the output of the `FromForm` derive yields about 315 lines of code for just that 4-variable struct (likely too much to replicate), and although it's possible to manually parse the raw `multipart/form-data` string with

```rust
fn post<'r>(form: String) -> Template {
```

that seems to undermine the point of using rocket.

Comment: From Form Trait is implemented for HashMap.

Comment: Yeah totally. I ended up rewriting my code to just have one HashMap per basic type, essentially working as a prefix on the web-side. Not super elegant, but it'll do.